# Positioned containers define a new stacking order, even when the computed z-index of the container is auto

Tags: z-index

Thanks for your positive response bt the major problem is that my apdivs are moving up/down when i zoom in/out my web browser.my coding is

```
    #apDiv7 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 723px;
        top: 1510px;
        width: 207px;
        height: 283px;
        z-index: 106;
    }

#apDiv9 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 947px;
    top: 1510px;
    width: 207px;
    height: 283px;
    z-index: 108;
}
#apDiv10 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 478px;
    top: 1510px;
    width: 207px;
    height: 283px;
    z-index: 109;
}
#apDiv56 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 478px;
    top: 1825px;
    width: 670px;
    height: 239px;
    z-index: 112;
}
#apDiv57 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 262px;
    top: 1825px;
    width: 194px;
    height: 239px;
    z-index: 113;
}
#apDiv59 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 266px;
    top: 487px;
    width: 453px;
    height: 28px;
    z-index: 114;
}
#apDiv60 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 965px;
    top: 2113px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    z-index: 115;
}
#apDiv61 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 478px;
    top: 539px;
    width: 670px;
    height: 422px;
    z-index: 116;
}
#apDiv62 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 478px;
    top: 1003px;
    width: 670px;
    height: 422px;
    z-index: 117;
}
```

my website is http://www.xstvshop.com/3in1_juicer.html
Your quick and effective response is highly appreciable thanks

Comment: That's a trippy effect when you scroll thru the css, due to the placement of whitespace :)

Comment: Ok i got your point, but how can we fix this because i am in a big trouble because when i remove whitespace from from my website, div tags still moves up and down,